# Add count from two queries in codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I have 4 tables 
I query:-
 1. activity: having activity id
 2. activity_specialties:having activity id and specialties
 3. users: specialties 
 4. List item

II query:

1. activity: having activity id
2. icd10_assignments:activity_assignment_id

I have to find count from I query and II query
and add those count result to find total result
 my columns are activity id and total count
My two queries are 
1)

```
SELECT `activity`.`activity_id`, count(distinct users.id) as user_id
FROM (`activity`)
JOIN `activity_specialties` ON `activity`.`activity_id` = `activity_specialties`.`activity_id`
LEFT JOIN `users` ON `users`.`specialty`= `activity_specialties`.`specialties_id`
WHERE `activity_category` =  'Online CME Activities'
GROUP BY `activity`.`activity_id`
```

2)

```
SELECT `activity`.`activity_id`, count(icd10_assignments.id) as assign_id
FROM (`activity`)
JOIN `icd10_assignments` 
ON `activity`.`activity_id`= `icd10_assignments`.`activity_assignment_id`
WHERE `activity_category` =  'Online CME Activities'
GROUP BY `activity`.`activity_id`
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need.   As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for help clarifying this question.

Comment: I have updated my questions with more details

Comment: as Khalid has pointed out, you are not very clear on what exactly your problem is. what is the problem you are encountering?

Comment: If I use union in both then it shows records of I query first and then II query result.But I want addition result of both count